# How to use Calc (or Excel) to reduce repetitive code editing while programming?

Tags: java, android, development-environment, editing

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797806/what-tricks-can-be-used-to-type-and-edit-code-faster was closed for not being constructive, so I will try to make this have a specific answer.

My question is specific to Android/Java but it applies to any programming language.

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.v_black:
    if (bgButtonIsSelected) {
        backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
    } else {
        textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
    }
    break;
case R.id.v_white:
    if (bgButtonIsSelected) {
        backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    } else {
        textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    }
    break;
}
```

Now I need to add more `case`s for all of the other colors. So everywhere it says "black" (or "white") I need to replace that with the other color names. The thing is, there are a lot of them. I've already written them all once and I don't feel like doing it again.

Here is where I wrote the colors before (in color.xml):

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>

<color name="red_100">#ffcdd2</color>
<color name="red_200">#ef9a9a</color>
<color name="red_500">#f44336</color>
<color name="red_800">#c62828</color>
<color name="pink_100">#f8bbd0</color>
<color name="pink_200">#f48fb1</color>
<color name="pink_500">#e91e63</color>
<color name="pink_800">#ad1457</color>
<color name="purple_100">#e1bee7</color>
<color name="purple_200">#ce93d8</color>
<color name="purple_500">#9c27b0</color>
<color name="purple_800">#6a1b9a</color>
<color name="deep_purple_100">#d1c4e9</color>
<color name="deep_purple_200">#b39ddb</color>
<color name="deep_purple_500">#673ab7</color>
<color name="deep_purple_800">#4527a0</color>
<color name="indigo_100">#c5cae9</color>
<color name="indigo_200">#9fa8da</color>
<color name="indigo_500">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="indigo_800">#283593</color>
<color name="blue_100">#bbdefb</color>
<color name="blue_200">#90caf9</color>
<color name="blue_500">#2196f3</color>
<color name="blue_800">#1565c0</color>
<color name="light_blue_100">#b3e5fc</color>
<color name="light_blue_200">#81d4fa</color>
<color name="light_blue_500">#03a9f4</color>
<color name="light_blue_800">#0277bd</color>
<color name="cyan_100">#b2ebf2</color>
<color name="cyan_200">#80deea</color>
<color name="cyan_500">#00bcd4</color>
<color name="cyan_800">#00838f</color>
<color name="teal_100">#b2dfdb</color>
<color name="teal_200">#80cbc4</color>
<color name="teal_500">#009688</color>
<color name="teal_800">#00695c</color>
<color name="green_100">#c8e6c9</color>
<color name="green_200">#a5d6a7</color>
<color name="green_500">#4caf50</color>
<color name="green_800">#2e7d32</color>
<color name="light_green_100">#dcedc8</color>
<color name="light_green_200">#c5e1a5</color>
<color name="light_green_500">#8bc34a</color>
<color name="light_green_800">#558b2f</color>
<color name="lime_100">#f0f4c3</color>
<color name="lime_200">#e6ee9c</color>
<color name="lime_500">#cddc39</color>
<color name="lime_800">#9e9d24</color>
<color name="yellow_100">#fff9c4</color>
<color name="yellow_200">#fff59d</color>
<color name="yellow_500">#ffeb3b</color>
<color name="yellow_800">#f9a825</color>
<color name="amber_100">#ffecb3</color>
<color name="amber_200">#ffe082</color>
<color name="amber_500">#ffc107</color>
<color name="amber_800">#ff8f00</color>
<color name="orange_100">#ffe0b2</color>
<color name="orange_200">#ffcc80</color>
<color name="orange_500">#ff9800</color>
<color name="orange_800">#ef6c00</color>
<color name="deep_orange_100">#ffccbc</color>
<color name="deep_orange_200">#ffab91</color>
<color name="deep_orange_500">#ff5722</color>
<color name="deep_orange_800">#d84315</color>
<color name="brown_100">#d7ccc8</color>
<color name="brown_200">#bcaaa4</color>
<color name="brown_500">#795548</color>
<color name="brown_800">#4e342e</color>
<color name="grey_100">#f5f5f5</color>
<color name="grey_200">#eeeeee</color>
<color name="grey_500">#9e9e9e</color>
<color name="grey_800">#424242</color>
<color name="blue_grey_100">#cfd8dc</color>
<color name="blue_grey_200">#b0bec5</color>
<color name="blue_grey_500">#607d8b</color>
<color name="blue_grey_800">#37474f</color>
```

I know I can just copy and paste but is there a faster way? How do I use Calc or Excel speed this process up?

(The answer below is something that saves me lots of time and I thought I would share it with other programmers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to isolate the color names that you have already written. They are currently in the following format:

```
<color name="COLOR_NAME">#80deea</color>
```

Copy the whole list and paste it into a spreadsheet program as **unformatted text** (Ctrl+Shift+V). (I am using LibreOffice Calc for my answer. I imagine the process is similar for Excel.) "Text Import" should pop up. In the "Separated by"/"Other" enter a double quote ("). (Because that is what surrounds the color name.) Say OK.

[image]

Now there are three columns with the color name in the second column. You can delete the first and third columns. We've isolated the color names.

The second step is to get those names into the right places in our code. The code we want to insert it in is in the following format:

```
case R.id.v_COLOR_NAME:
if (bgButtonIsSelected) {
    backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.COLOR_NAME);
} else {
    textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.COLOR_NAME);
}
break;
```

Take out the line breaks so that it is on a single line like this:

```
case R.id.v_COLOR_NAME: if (bgButtonIsSelected) {backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.COLOR_NAME);} else { textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.COLOR_NAME);} break;
```

There are three `COLOR_NAME` places so that divides the line into four parts. Copy each part and paste it at the top of a column in Calc. Then copy those four cells all the way down for every color name.

[image]

Now in the top row off to the right (I'm going to use column H from the last picture.) write the following formula to concatenate all the pieces together:

```
=D1&B1&E1&B1&F1&B1&G1
```

where column B is the `COLOR_NAME` and columns D, E, F, and G are the four parts of the code. Copy the formula in this cell all the way down. Now when I copy this column it gives me

```
"case R.id.v_red_100: if (bgButtonIsSelected) {backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_100);} else {  textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_100);} break;"
"case R.id.v_red_200: if (bgButtonIsSelected) {backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_200);} else {  textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_200);} break;"
"case R.id.v_red_500: if (bgButtonIsSelected) {backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_500);} else {  textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_500);} break;"
"case R.id.v_red_800: if (bgButtonIsSelected) {backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_800);} else {  textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_800);} break;"
"case R.id.v_pink_100: if (bgButtonIsSelected) {backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.pink_100);} else {    textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.pink_100);} break;"
...
```

Hmm... Calc put it in quotes so I need to remove those. I paste everything into a LibreOffice Writer (or Word or whatever you use) and replace `"case` with `case` and `break;"` with `break;`. (I could use a regular expression that Writer supports but I always forget the expression for beginning and end of line. It was faster to do it this way than to look it up on StackOverflow.)

Finally, you can past all that into your code editor. If your editor is any good it will auto format it as it should be. (Cntl+Shift+F in Eclipse.)

Tadaa! With all the time I saved I had time to make you this tutorial. I hope others can enjoy it as much as I do.

Comment: While I appreciate that you took the time to do all this, it sure seems like the absolute wrong tool for the job. A column selection, or even a trivial xpath in a tool like xmlstar, or a simple editor regex yields the colors. An editor macro or trivial script can generate the code. Though it should be a simple map anyway, as noted.

Comment: You're right. I guess I was writing this for other non-advanced programmers like myself. These are tools that everyone is familiar with and no knowledge of macros or script writing is necessary.

Comment: Perhaps you could use this technique to generate the code that goes in the initMap() function of @Gabe Sechan's answer? So, it's not a total waste.

Comment: =) Yes. Actually, I already did. Even if other people don't like this method, I learned a lesson about about writing clearer code from his answer, so it wasn't a wasted post.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need excel or calc, you need to structure your programming right.

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> idToColor = new Map<Integer, Integer>(); 

//at init time
void initMap(){
    idToColor.add(R.id.v_white, R.color.v_white);
    //1 line per color
}
```

Then your switch becomes:

```
Integer color = idToColor.get(view.getId());
if(color != null){
    if (bgButtonIsSelected) {
        backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(color.getValue());
    } else {
        textColor = getResources().getColor(color.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now adding a color is 1 line-  adding it to the map.

Comment: I agree that this is a superior programming structure, but don't you ever have to write things more than once? The color names are here in your map. But they are also in color.xml. The similarly named Views are also in the layout xml. Don't you have to write all of these separately? The code I posted was just an example to illustrate the problem of repetitive code entry in order to share how I solved that using Calc (using StackOverflow's Q&A format).

Comment: Never, if you have to write something more than once you are doing it wrong.  DRY is the difference between a hacker and a programmer, the most important difference.  In fact, I'd say that I would prefer horrible broken DRY code over working copy and paste or generated code every single time (because at least I can fix the DRY code).  Let me make that more clear here: DO NOT GENERATE CODE! It's bad for everyone.

Comment: I won't go quite as strong as never, if I had to do 3-4 colors I'd be copy-pasting. But yeah, if I'm repeating code it means I'm probably doing something wrong.  And if I need to generate code-  its going to be done by a documented program checked into source control, not excel.  Although that probably shouldn't be done by a novice.